# Why would one control get redrawn more frequently than another when both are being invalidated?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an winforms application with two controls in which I do custom drawing.  The main control shows a small section of a long continuous image of a road, while the other control shows a horizontally-squashed representation of the entire road image.  The second control is used to navigate the first: you can click anywhere in the overview to scroll to that location in the main view.  Here's a screenshot, where the main view is on top and the overview is on bottom:

[image: screenshot of both controls]

There's a cyan line in the overview control that indicates the position of the imagery being shown in the main view.  (In this screenshot, it's just over 1/3 the width from the left.)  The user can click and drag that line in the overview, which will cause the main view to scroll.

I've noticed something odd about the redrawing:  When I'm dragging the cyan line in the overview control, the main view gets redrawn much more often than the overview, even though both are invalidated in response to the mouse move.  I know that WM_PAINT messages only get sent when there are no other messages in the queue, but I don't understand why one control would get redrawn more often than the other if they're both being invalidated at the same time.

Actually, as I was typing that last sentence I think I stumbled on the reason.  Tell me if this sounds right:

Each control has its own message queue, and the main control isn't receiving any input-related messages, so its message queue is empty more often than that of the overview, which has to process all the mouse events.  So it receives the WM_PAINT message more often than the overview.

So at this point, I guess the question is, "Does that make sense?  Is that what's happening?"

Comment: How is the "horizontally-squashed representation of the entire road image" in the overview achieved?  Are you doing calculations in the Paint() event, or iterating over some data and custom painting the lines at positions?  I'm guessing it simply takes longer to draw the overview than  the main view.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, actually I've recently optimized the drawing of the overview control so that it keeps a Bitmap of the last full render and just blits that plus drawing the cyan line when scrolling.  It only updates the Bitmap when the scene actually changes, which is rare and definitely doesn't happen during scrolling.  But even if it does take longer to render the overview than the main view, if they were happening with the same frequency the effect would just be general sluggishness, which is not what I'm seeing.  The main control is keeping up with mouse events while the overview is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory is not sound, there is only one message queue per thread.  What you see is almost certainly caused by the way WM_PAINT is generated.  It is only delivered when the queue is *empty*.  That makes it a "low priority" message, user input always goes first.  Important that it works that way, you would not want user input to get lost, or the message queue to explode, because painting code is slow.

So, roughly, you called Invalidate() twice.  The bottom-most window gets the Paint event but by the time it is finished there is yet another mouse event waiting to be processed.  So the second window does *not* get its paint event and you'll invalidate a window that is already invalidated.  Only when you slow down the mouse, or stop moving it, can it catch up.

Easy to see from Task Manager, you'll see the UI thread of your program burning 100% core.

Forcing a paint anyway is possible, but you have to call Update() instead of Invalidate().  Your program still burns 100% core but now instead of skipping paints it will be less responsive to the mouse.  That sounds dangerous, with the potential to flood the message queue, but it is not.  WM_MOUSEMOVE does not get added to the message queue either.  Like WM_PAINT, it only gets generated when the queue is empty.  You'll get it first.

Comment: I think I mostly understand this explanation, but what makes it so it's always the top control that gets the WM_PAINT when the message queue is empty and the bottom one that doesn't get it because events came in?  Why is it never the other way around?  Just luck of the draw?  Something about their relative order within the control hierarchy?

Comment: Not the "top control", Windows uses the "painter's algorithm" and paints from back to front.  Where "back" is the lowest one in the Z-order.  Z-order is not always obvious when controls do not overlap each other, it is visible from the View > Other Windows > Document Outline tool window.  The "Bring to Front" and "Send to Back" designer commands modify it.

Comment: Yeah, I meant "top control in my screenshot."  I just meant, my main view always seems to be the control that successfully redraws and my overview control always seems to be the control that doesn't get WM_PAINT because new mouse events have come in.  And I think you're saying that's just a byproduct of how I arranged them in the designer and that I might see different behavior if I rearranged them.  Is that correct?  If so, it sounds a bit precarious and I might want to switch to your suggestion of using Update().

Comment: That is what I'm saying.  You have a good reason to use Update() instead.

Comment: Thanks much for the help.